# Laravel File Storage Location

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I am running my Laravel Project on centos, using the default artisan server.
I am trying to add data to files, using laravel File::append command.
In config/filesystems.php i have the following:

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('data'),
    ],
```

and

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
*/

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
```

and 'FILESYSTEM_DRIVER' is not defined in the .env file.
However when i use File::append(), the files are created in the public folder, and not storage_path

Any idea what is causing this?What am i missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Storage::put('filename.jpg', $contents);` uses the default filesystem and thus expects a relative filename, `File::append` does not.

So a possible solution here could be `File::append($path, 'yourAppend');` with the full path to your file in the storage folder.